# Есть скрипт, который необходимо сделать так, чтоб числа не обновлялись при перезагрузке странице,а навсегда оставались теми,которые были сгенерированы

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Сайт находится на движке вордпресс, возможно можно решить как то через кеширование, но тогда ж при очистке кеша числа обновятся, но это уже хоть какой то выход. Может можно как то сохранять на сервер посредством php? Там суть такая, есть страничка на вордпресе и блок с скриптом где постоянно обновляются числа при перезагрузке страницы, а надо чтоб сгенерило навсегда.

```
<script>
var min = 1;
var max = 90;
//Number of numbers to extract
var stop = 6;

var numbers = [];

for (let i = 0; i < stop; i++) {
  var n =  Math.floor(Math.random() * max) + min;
  var check = numbers.includes(n);
  
  if(check === false) {
    numbers.push(n);
  } else {
    while(check === true){
      n = Math.floor(Math.random() * max) + min;
      check = numbers.includes(n);
        if(check === false){
          numbers.push(n);
        }
     }
  }
}

sort();


//Sort the array in ascending order
function sort() {
  numbers.sort(function(a, b){return a-b});
  document.getElementById("array_number").innerHTML = numbers.join(" - ");
}
</script>

<h2 style="text-align: center;">Casual numbers no repeat</h2>
<p id="array_number" style="font-size: 25px; text-align: center;"></p>
```

Comment: Сколько ненужных букв... Через них трудно пробраться к сути. Но если я правильно понял, то речь идёт о "сгенерировать случайное число с постоянным хранением". При этом с ним же ещё нужно как-то дальше работать, ведь Посему нужно писать нормальное ТЗ (без воды и придыханий) и искать специалиста, способного написать плагин по этим требованиям.

Answer (score -1):

Как насчёт использования [local Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)?
Я не знаю лучшего способа реализовать это используя JS, всеравно весь кеш будь он на php или js легко почистить, я думаю можно реализовать на php привязку к айпи, но это уже куда сложнее и необходима база данных и в целом это будет неэффективно

```
<h2 style="text-align: center;">Casual numbers no repeat</h2>
<p id="array_number" style="font-size: 25px; text-align: center;"></p>

<script>


var min = 1;
var max = 90;
//Number of numbers to extract
var stop = 6;

var numbers = []


for (let i = 0; i < stop; i++) {
  var n =  Math.floor(Math.random() * max) + min;
  var check = numbers.includes(n);
  
  if(check === false) {
    numbers.push(n);
  } else {
    while(check === true){
      n = Math.floor(Math.random() * max) + min;
      check = numbers.includes(n);
        if(check === false){
          numbers.push(n);
        }
     }
  }
}

// Проверяем существует ли такая запись в локальном хранилище, если нет то записываем
if ( window.localStorage.getItem('numbersArray') ) {
    numbers = window.localStorage.getItem('numbersArray').split(',');
}
else {  
    window.localStorage.setItem('numbersArray',numbers);
}

sort()

//Sort the array in ascending order
function sort() {
  numbers.sort(function(a, b){return a-b});
  document.getElementById("array_number").innerHTML = numbers.join(" - ");
}

</script>
```

Comment: локалсторедж это не только не "навсегда", но и "для всех по-разному". Только запись в базу решит хотелку ТСа.

Comment: А база чем поможет?

Comment: Всем - и вечным хранением и для всех будет одно и тоже число. Более того - доставать из базы для дальнейшей работы с ним намного проще и понятней.

Comment: Но ведь в таком случае будет достаточно json файла или даже обычной переменной, а генерация чисел становится вовсе бесполезной функцией

Comment: Что за чушь ты мелешь.. Осиль вопрос. Там задача  а) генерация числа и б) сохранение его навсегда  (перевожу: для всех юзеров одно и тоже число. И что не сказано - для постоянного использования в ВП.)

Comment: Простите, я понимаю по другому 1) генерация числа для каждого пользователя 2) сохранения этого числа для него навсегда. Даже если я окажусь не прав, то почему необходим сервер, когда можно тот же результат записать в простую переменную...

Comment: А причём тут тогда очистка кеша, если серверный кеш почистить может только он сам? Если взять оригинальный вопрос, который ты изменил, человек говорит что он вообще не кодер, откуда он может знать такие нюансы? Я сказал что я не противлюсь твоему мнению, я оставил ответ потому что считаю что он ищет возможности сгенерировать для каждого пользователя числа и сохранить их

Comment: Как раз и необходимо, чтобы генерировало для всех по разному, разово

Comment: После очистки истории браузера, числа генерируются по новому( А как можно занести в ДЖСОН файл? Думаю это решит задачу

Comment: Подождите, надо начать с того что джсон не решит проблему того что при очистке Кеша удаляются числа, варианта точного их сохранения навсегда просто не существует, кеш легко чиститься, айпи, устройство регулярно меняется. Либо вам необходимо писать целую систему регистрации и авторизации, либо использовать какой-либо другой способ

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное!!!